# DRF won't send a raw JSON string to browser. it returns a string that is JSON, want to bypass calling json.load

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

We have large JSON blobs stored in the database we want to pass to the frontend using DRF.

Instead of parsing that JSON string then having it decode, could we have it just return the JSON string itself?

For example, is there a way for this to to be sent to the frontend:

```
Response({ 'json': '{"example": "json-from-database"}' }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Right now this will create an undesired JSON response that looks like this:

```
{ 'json': '{"example": "json-from-database"}' }
```

We want it to create a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{ 'json': {"example": "json-from-database"} }
```

Is there a way to send 'raw' JSON response to the frontend without it having to parse/decode our existing JSON string?

At the moment we are using `json.load`.

**Edit, clarification:**

The client sees a JSON response but it has a property containing a *string* of JSON.  Since the JSON is already valid, I just want to return the string and have the client consume instead of Python try parse/decode it.

Comment: A little confused. Your claimed undesired JSON is exactly what you show in your example? `Response({ 'json': '{"example": "json-from-database"}' }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
`

Comment: It will send a JSON string to the browser, but the JSON itself is fine.  I don't want to have to convert it to a python dict then have it convert that parsed back to real JSON.  I want the Python version of this `{ 'json': '{"example": "json-from-database"}'}` to be rendered as  this when the client receives it: `{ 'json': {"example": "json-from-database"} }`

Comment: I did an edit, which will maybe clarify it.  I just don't want `Response` to do run it's encoder on the data passed to it.  I want an exception where it allows me to return a 'raw' JSON string.

Comment: But it is not server side's business. Whatever you return, they are just normal bytes. The client parses it as JSON just because of `Content-Type`. In this case, you should implement a different parse function on client side.

Comment: The client could parse the JSON but in our case it is not ideal since it makes debugging more difficult when problems come up... for us, the benefit of just sending the raw JSON outweighs having the client parse it.

Comment: Well, so you have to reconstruct it on Server side. There is nothing django can do as it just returns the raw string(generated by json.dumps) and set content-type to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay your question is a little confusing, but going off this: "I did an edit, which will maybe clarify it. I just don't want Response to do run it's encoder on the data passed to it. I want an exception where it allows me to return a 'raw' JSON string. " I think you are just looking to skip the parsing computation on the server-side? If so:

```
database_json = '{"from": ["the", "database"]}'
raw_json = '{"json": {"example": %s}}' % database_json
return HTTPResponse(raw_json, content_type='application/json')
```

If you need some validation/flexibility on the 'json' and 'example' parts of the JSON then it's a little harder and you'll have to make a custom encoder and monkey-patch the string escaping (since it will escape the double quotes).:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import json

class RawJSON(str):
  def __init__(self, raw_json):
    return super(RawJSON, self).__init__(raw_json)


class JSONEncoderWithRawSupport(json.JSONEncoder):
  @contextmanager
  def patched_encoder(self):
    default_encoder = json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii

    def _encode(o):
        if isinstance(o, RawJSON):
            return o
        return default_encoder(o)
    json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = _encode
    yield
    json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = default_encoder

  def iterencode(self, *args, **kwargs):
    with self.patched_encoder():
        return super(JSONEncoderWithRawSupport, self).iterencode(*args, **kwargs)     


database_json = RawJSON('{"from": ["the", "database"]}')
my_dict = {"json": {"example": database_json}}
my_json = json.dumps(my_dict, cls=JSONEncoderWithRawSupport)
return HTTPResponse(my_json, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Going to mark this as the answer for now since it looks like it would fit what we're trying to achieve the best (and we're not using a serializer where the other answer would make more sense).  Thank you!

Comment: Yeah it depends what you need. The other answer is good if you need something simple and you don't care about the JSON parsing computation (ie. in most cases). This answer is suitable if you do indeed care about the parsing expense. If you aren't already using a serializer and you don't care about the parsing cost, your initial json.load solution works fine

Answer (score 2):

Use [**`JSONField`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield) of DRF Serializer

```
#serializer.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class Myserializer(serializers.Serializer):
    myjson = serializers.JSONField()


#views.py
class MyView(....):
    .....
    myjson = {"myjson":{some requeried json}}
    serializer = Myserializer(myjson)
    serializer.is_valid(True)
    return Response(data=serializer.data)
```